# Trouble positioning images within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I used instafeed.js to pull the 3 most recent images from an instagram account. It loads the images into a div, and I managed to style the images the way they need to be. The problem though is that they way I set it up is pretty static. If I view the page on a bigger screen, the images are in a row of three and not positioned correctly. Also, If one of the images is more wide than tall it will not align with the bottom of the big image on the left and look weird. I posted a screenshot below of how it looks on my macbook (which is what it always needs to look like regardless of screen or picture size), and another screenshot of what it looks like on a bigger screen. Any help is very appreciated!

What it needs to look like always:
[image]

What happens on a bigger screen size:
[image]

Instafeed.js:

```
  var feed = new Instafeed ({
    get: "user",
    userId: "1957779802",
    limit: 3,
    sortBy: "most-recent",
    resolution: "standard_resolution",
    template: '<div class="img"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>',
    accessToken: "1957779802.bef71cd.f6782544ba674fc3af9dddb2fec415fe"
  });
  feed.run();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col2">

      <div id="instafeed"></div>

      <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQEXfLzrNpxe7AZme3dTP0w" target="_blank"><img class="yt-bg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/youtube-img.jpg" alt="Youtube" /><span class="covered"><div class="play"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/play-img.png"></img></div><div class="text"><h3>Press Play!</h3><p>Watch clips on our YouTube channel.</p></div></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-container .row1 .col2 .instafeed {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.social-container .row1 .col2 .img {
  margin: 5px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-container .row1 .col2 .img a img {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.social-container .row1 .col2 .img a img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 152px;
}

.social-container .row1 .col2 .img:first-child {
  margin-right: 30px
}

.social-container .row1 .col2 .img:first-child a img {
  width: 330px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

well, what you need to do is called responsive design. 
Right now you only have fixed width's wich naturally can't scale up. 
If you want to style them for specific Display-widths I would recommend using @media in your stylesheet to talk specificly to larger screens.

You can then size your images in percentages to make sure they scale up. But after one specificly large width I would recommend stopping the scaling because your images only have a limited resolution. To style that you can either work with @media screen and (min-width: 1440px) or set a max-width to the image itself. But if you want to make your site responsive it will take a while and you have to

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!